# Opening a Adobe Flex project using FlashDevelop

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

I am trying to open a flex project( created using Adobe Flex) using FlashDevelop.
How would I do this? Would someone be able to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Flex is an SDK that includes an ActionScript UI Framework and a compiler along with some other goodies.  It doesn't have the concept of a project.

I assume, however, that you want to open a project created using Flash Builder in FlashDevelop.  Is that correct?   As far as I know there is no way to do this.  Flash Builder is an Eclipse based IDE; and I thought FlashDevelop was their own system.

You'll have to create a new project in FlashDevelop.  You should, however, be able to use the same Flex code.  [Here are some instructions](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3).

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I did try to follow the instructions yesterday before posting this..but I get this error in flashdevelop when opening - "No SDK descriptor found".. any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: I never used FlashDevelop, so I'm not sure.  The only thing that came up in a Google Search was the new question you posted on StackOverflow.  Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

In FD, you click on the Project menu, then choose "import project". Then you browse to the directory where the Flex project is, and select the file called .actionScriptProperties and click open.